# remove agent from assembler delay part

Tags: anylogic

I have a problem to manually remove/delete the agents from my assembler block (delay part). I would like to remove/delete the agents in the assembler with the click of a button. I think the problem is that remove() only removes the agents in the queue part of the assembler and not of the delay part right?

[The "Reset" button should remove all agents from the two queue blocks and the assembler block.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PM29k.png)

I wrote the following code in the action of the button. Unfortunately the if condition doesn't work. Nevertheless, the agent remains in the delay part of the assembler. Does anyone have a solution suggestion for me?

```
while(Lager_Oberteile.size() > 0) {
      Agent agent = Lager_Oberteile.removeFirst();
}
while(Lager_Plättchen.size() > 0) {
      Agent agent = Lager_Plättchen.removeFirst();
}
if (Klebestation.delaySize() == 1) {
     Klebestation.remove(Oberteil_Plättchen_geklebt) ;
}

offene_Aufträge = 0;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to know what agent is in the delay of the assember, one way is to do this:

```
Agent a=assembler.delayGet(0); //the first agent in the delay
assembler.remove(a);
```

Done

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to access the Delay within the service within the assembler (these are nested blocks essentially) and remove the agent from the delay:

So to remove the oldest agent in the assembler's delay, you can use

```
myAssemblerBlock.service.delay.stopDelay(agent);
```